# Excel conditional formatting for previous value in same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am looking forward to update the excel cell in colour based on the data received from an external source. The data is getting updated as expected in a cell. I want to change the colour of the cell based on the received data.

Assume the selected cell is A3. The data comes in a internal of 3 seconds. Assume data that comes is 10 15 12 18 20. For these data I want the colour to be red green red green green.

Red indicates that the value is less than the previous value and green indicates that the value has increases as compared to previous value.

I have used conditional formatting, but did not find a feature to compare previous value in same cell

Comment: `rapidjson` is a C++ library. Please update the question tags.

Comment: I have written a sample code and compiled with g++

Comment: what else can be done to loop and get the count? printf("%s\n", d[0]["Data1"].GetString()); and printf("%s\n", d[1]["Data1"].GetString()); gives the desired output. I just want to count and assign it to variable i. Rest all are working fine.

Comment: @David Collins Also can you please give me the changes to be done if I have to write it for C?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get array data from json file using rapidjson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857349/get-array-data-from-json-file-using-rapidjson)

Comment: Also maybe you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303257/looping-over-an-array-in-rapidjson-and-getting-the-object-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose V is a `JSON object` which has a `key-value object`. You can retrieve data like this.

```
const rapidjson::Value& V;
for (Value::ConstMemberIterator iter = V.MemberBegin(); iter != V.MemberEnd(); ++iter){
    printf("%s\t", iter->name.GetString());
    printf("%s\t", iter->value.GetString());
}
```

([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215036/10035556).)

Comment: Can I know the required changes to write the above code in C?

Comment: You need to re-implement rapidjson in C.
or You can create dll/so file in C++ and use it in C code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575060/c-dll-to-be-used-in-c-program

Comment: Thanks will check the same. Can you please let me know on the V JSON object used here?

Comment: You can also check this https://blog.manash.me/parsing-json-using-c-quick-introduction-to-jsmn-library-92d1e49559e8

Comment: "Suppose V is a JSON object", can you let me know how you have defined this object?

Comment: Getting below error:

error: ‘V’ declared as reference but not initialized
 const rapidjson::Value& V;
                         ^

Comment: V is a JSON object try to replace it with your JSON object

Comment: you mean const char* json in my sample code?  If I do that it will be conflicting right?

Comment: If I do "for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)" it works as expected. I just want to replace the 2, with the actual count of array.

Comment: I am new to this topic and not able to get exact reply for my query. Apologies for the same.